Authentication Issues in Blazor Application After IIS Restart
I'm encountering a significant issue with authentication in my Blazor application hosted on a Windows Server within a LAN environment.
Problem Description:
Whenever I turn off the IIS server to install updates for the application and then turn it back on, users find themselves logged into incorrect accounts. For example, I might be logged in as Admin, but after the restart, I find myself connected as a different user. This issue affects all users on the LAN, causing them to be logged in as different accounts, not their own. Additionally, the logout function ceases to work properly when this happens.
Here are additional details about my setup:

IIS Server Version: 10.0.17763.1
Authentication Method: ASP.NET Core Identity.
Server Environment: The application is hosted on a server that is part of an Active Directory (AD) domain.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any insights on what might be causing this problem? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

If you go through Microsoft documentation, there is nothing called "ASP.NET Authentication". Please edit the question and reveal more about your code/IIS configuration, so people can see what actually you are using. Besides, you might need to add a network topology diagram to show if any load balancer is involved.

Actually I'm using "ASP.NET Core Identity". Someone told me that I need to configure the data protection stack..
